# pass json in post request python for commiting files

Tags: python, json, post, python-2.x

I am trying to pass JSON in post request using Python.
Below is the code

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen        
values = """[{"n": "MyApexClass","r": false,"t": "ApexClass"},{"n": "SysAdmin","r": false,"t": "Profile"}]"""

request = Request('https://copado.herokuapp.com/json/v1/webhook/'
                'commitFiles/user_story_idapi_key=user_api_key&commitMessage=commitMessage', data=values)

response_body = urlopen(request).read()

print response_body
```

But I am getting below error

```
{"error":"Malformed payload, could not parse metadata json!!!"}
```

Please help me.

Comment: I agree with Nick; Try deleting the string quotes around the values line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use values not as a string, use as python object

```
values = [
    {"n": "MyApexClass", "r": False, "t": "ApexClass"},
    {"n": "SysAdmin", "r": False, "t": "Profile"}
]

values = json.dumps(values).encode('utf8')

req = Request(your_url, data=values,
              headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
```

Comment: I tried. But getting below error.                                                   
`response_body = urlopen(request).read()
 
TypeError: write() argument 1 must be string or read-only buffer, not list`

Comment: That error is resolved. But, now getting different error. `{"status":"error","isFinished":false,"isSuccess":false,"error":"Webhook error - Insufficient credits to perform action"}`

Comment: That error on server-side you didn't have rights/credits to use that method.

Comment: @diwakarg you are get an answer to your first question, set that answer as right and ask another question.